# MySQL Left() or SUBSTRING()?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

Both of these queries will produce same result. But which one is better, faster.

```
SELECT LEFT(textField, 100) AS first100Chars

SELECT SUBSTRING(textField, 1, 100 )
```

Thanks.

Comment: They are probably treated the same by the engine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By itself there is little difference, however `left` can potentially utilize an index while `substring` cannot.

Comment: on a text field, which is not an index, is there any difference in performance?

Comment: you create index on top of the field to speed up selects, it's not an `or`

Answer (score 1):

Substring will take little more time than left function. Though your case is straight forward use left function only.