# Delete characters if the row size more than 9-characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have more than 12000 rows in my sql table and i want to delete exceed characters from the row if it contains more than 9 character.

Before:

```
Id----Title
1-----Great Day For Summer
```

After:

```
Id----Title
1-----Great Day
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382706/mysql-left-or-substring) about `SUBSTRING` and `LEFT`.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the characters?  Just use `left(title, 9)` when you query the table.

Comment: Fix the front-end moving forward to limit input length

Answer (score 0):

Use substring to get the first 9 characters.

```
update tablename set title = substring(title,1,9)
```

You can also add a where clause to make sure only too long values are updated, to keep transaction size down:

```
update tablename set title = substring(title,1,9)
where length(title) > 9
```

(Is length MySQL?)