# MYSQL: LEFT() not using any index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I just ran into an issue with my mysql using a where condition such as `WHERE LEFT(`field`, 4) = "abcd"`. I'm currently trying to optimize my queries and i noticed it isn't using any of my defined indices. I thought `LEFT()` has the potential to use indices while `SUBSTRING` is not? (i.e. mentioned in the answer to this question: [MySQL Left() or SUBSTRING()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382706/mysql-left-or-substring))

So in my case the field is called `category CHAR(6)`, in the table `image`. For testing i have defined a variety of indices:

```
ALTER TABLE image ADD INDEX `cat` (`category`);
ALTER TABLE image ADD INDEX `cat2` (`category(2)`);
ALTER TABLE image ADD INDEX `cat4` (`category(4)`);
```

and an primary index on `id`, a simple index on field `type` as well as one `FULLTEXT` on other columns, i don't think they mattassaer.

Although i get the follwing results:

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM image i0_ WHERE LEFT(category,4) = "0000" LIMIT 0,30`

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i0_   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 617359 | Using where |

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: You **could** use a GENERATED column and index that - VIRTUAL so no space overhead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `LIKE` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM image i0_ WHERE category LIKE "0000%" LIMIT 0,30
```

This will allow it to use the index. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-btree-hash.html):

> The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character. For example, the following SELECT statements use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Pat%_ck%';
> ```

Comment: The `_i0` is an alias that isn't used. It's totally unnecessary in this case but it shouldn't break the query.

Comment: Thanks you, this is actually true. I was under the impression `LEFT` could be used with indexes. Using `LIKE` seems to do the trick. `i0_`: I know, actually this is query coming out of Doctrine, so in reality there's no `*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use function in search then it will not use index, instead you can use like but left side should be constant not variable as @Mark Byers suggested.

Below statement will not use index

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE LEFT(category,4) = "0000" LIMIT 0,30
```

Below statement also will not use index

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE categor like "%0000%" LIMIT 0,30
```

Below statement will use index

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE categor like "0000%" LIMIT 0,30
```